# PyQT6/PySide6: How to make a QWidget always on top of screen?

Tags: user-interface, pyqt, pyside, pyside6, pyqt6

I am making a floating clock based on PySide6, its main part is as follows

How can I make this program always on top of the screen, even in full screen mode?

The `self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)` method doesn't seem to work.

```py
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import QPoint, Qt, QTime, QTimer
from PySide6.QtGui import QAction, QFont, QMouseEvent
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMenu, QVBoxLayout, QWidget


class Clock(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.left = 1100
        self.top = 800
        self.width = 320
        self.height = 60
        # UI
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self) -> None:

        # geometry of main window
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        # hide frame
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        # font
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(50)

        # label object
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setFont(font)

        # layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self, spacing=0)

        layout.addWidget(self.label)  # add label
        self.setLayout(layout)

        # timer object
        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)
        timer.start(1000)  # update the timer per second
        self.show()

    def showTime(self) -> None:

        current_time = QTime.currentTime()  # get the current time
        label_time = current_time.toString('hh:mm')  # convert timer to string
        self.label.setText(label_time)  # show it to the label


if __name__ == '__main__':

    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    clock = Clock()
    clock.show()  # show all the widgets
    App.exit(App.exec())  # start the app
```

Comment: If several windows set that flag (or similar), how would the window manager know which one should be on top?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I am a beginner, this app only has one window, I don't get that `several windows`, should I make the class `Clock` to inherit `QMainWindow` instead of `QWidget` ?

Comment: You want your window to always be on top of *other external windows*, right? An external full screen window may already have the always-on-top flag set. It's not possible for two windows to *both* be on top. There's no super-flag that will override all other flags.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong method for setting the flags individually. You should use this method instead: `setWindowFlag` NOT `setWindowFlags` (without the "s" at the end). This will solve Your issue:

```
self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint, True)
self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint, True)
```

To use `setWindowFlags` (with the "s" at the end) You should combine the flags with the bitwise OR.
Here is the (C++) Qt-example for that https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html